# Can I nest a With inside a With when both are designating a different sheet in the same workbook? VBA

Tags: excel, vba, nested, with-statement

Basically, I've got a workbook that imports values from one sheet, then allows you to select some, add extra data, then transfers the selected items, your added values, and additional info contained in the sheet whose values are pulled from initially to another workbook. I need to be able to match the values inside the initial worksheet with the corresponding info in the other sheet (in the same workbook) so that I can take data from both and loop them in. I am worried that I am not allowed to nest my Withs when they both designate worksheets within the same workbook because I keep getting Error 91 (Object variable or With block variable not set). Is this true?

```
Dim RMs As Worksheet
Dim FLF As Worksheet
Set RMs = Workbooks("FLF Coding Trials.xlsm").Worksheets("Program")
Set FLF = Workbooks("FLF Template.xlsx").Worksheets("FLF Sheet")

Dim lng As Long
Dim cnt As Long
Dim check As Long
Dim length As Long

Dim namecheck As Range
Dim vencheck As Range

With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Program")
lng = Me.Cells(.Rows.Count, "N").End(xlUp).Row
For cnt = 1 To lng - 1 Step 1
    'The two below lines work reliably
    FLF.Range("B" & cnt + 23).Value = Me.Range("N" & cnt + 1).Value
    FLF.Range("N" & cnt + 23).Value = Me.Range("P" & cnt + 1).Value

    'Adding the following variable designations and the With gives me the error. If I change the below two variables to strings I get a compile error
    namecheck.Value = Range("N" & cnt + 1).Value
    vencheck.Value = Range("P" & cnt + 1).Value

        With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Names and Vendors")
        length = Me.Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
        check = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Names and Vendors").Evaluate("MATCH(1,(B1:B" & length & "=""" & namecheck.Value & """)*(C1:C" & length & "=""" & vencheck.Value & """),0)")
        'more commands will go here
        End With
    Next cnt
End With
```

Comment: Since you don't actually make use of the second `With` (the one for "Names and vendors"), why not just remove it?

Comment: I will be. I'll be putting a loop in there to loop in all the extra data contained within, as designated by the 'more commands will go here' comment.

Comment: Yes you can nest With blocks but there can only be one acting scope - that will be the scope of whatever is the closest `With`

Comment: Sorry, but can you elaborate? I assumed that whatever is contained inside the With would only finish via either by an End With command or by nesting another With in it (as I tried here).

Comment: I am trying to replicate the Error 91.  Is the above code in Trials, Template, or elsewhere?  Is it in a sheet module or a class module?  How is the above code executed?  Is above code in a Sub or Function?  In order to determine which line of code is failing.

Comment: If you're in a `With` and your code enters a second `With` (without first having hit an `End With` then the scope defined by the second `With` becomes the active scope until you hit the `End With`

Comment: It activates when clicking an ActiveX button in the Program sheet. Code is in Trials under a Private Sub.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're in a `With` block and your code enters a second `With` (without first having hit an `End With`) then the scope defined by the second `With` becomes the active scope until you hit the `End With` (or another `With`)

```
With A
   'scope here is A
   With B
       'scope here is B
   End with
   'scope here is A
End With
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many issues in your code, none of which have anything to do with the `With` blocks.

Based on a comment *I assumed that Me designated the object in the scoped With* use of `Me.` should be replaced with just `.`

See annotaions in code below marked with `'~~~`

```
Dim RMs As Worksheet
Dim FLF As Worksheet
Set RMs = Workbooks("FLF Coding Trials.xlsm").Worksheets("Program")
Set FLF = Workbooks("FLF Template.xlsx").Worksheets("FLF Sheet")

Dim lng As Long
Dim cnt As Long
Dim check As Long
Dim length As Long

Dim namecheck As Range
Dim vencheck As Range

With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Program")
    '~~~ .Rows refers to ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Program").Rows
    lng = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "N").End(xlUp).Row '~~~ drop the Me
    For cnt = 1 To lng - 1 Step 1
        'The two below lines work reliably
        '~~~ Me implies this code is in a Worksheet code behind module, and refers to that sheet.  Is this what you intend?
        FLF.Range("B" & cnt + 23).Value = .Range("N" & cnt + 1).Value '~~~ drop the Me
        FLF.Range("N" & cnt + 23).Value = .Range("P" & cnt + 1).Value '~~~ drop the Me

        'Adding the following variable designations and the With gives me the error. If I change the below two variables to strings I get a compile error
        '~~~ there is no reference to the With block in these 2 lines of code
        '~~~ And you havn't Set namecheck or vencheck. Add
        Set namecheck = FLF.Range("B" & cnt + 23) '~~~ or whatever range you actually meant
        Set vencheck = FLF.Range("N" & cnt + 23)
        namecheck.Value = Range("N" & cnt + 1).Value '~~~ the unqualified Range(...) refers to the ActiveSheet.  Maybe should be .Range? 
        vencheck.Value = Range("P" & cnt + 1).Value

        With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Names and Vendors")
            '~~~ .Rows now refers to ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Names and Vendors").Rows
            length = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row '~~~ drop the Me
            '~~~ you can leave out ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Names and Vendors") as this is in the With block for that sheet
            check = .Evaluate("MATCH(1,(B1:B" & length & "=""" & namecheck.Value & """)*(C1:C" & length & "=""" & vencheck.Value & """),0)")
            'more commands will go here
        End With
        '~~~ .Anything now refers to ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Program").Anything again
    Next cnt
End With
```

Comment: Thank you very much. As you can tell, I'm sitting here with a VBA textbook my buddy lent me and using Google to try and bend this language to my purposes. I don't understand what you mean when talking about "Me" though. I have been using it to refer to the ActiveSheet basically. I assumed that Me designated the object in the scoped With.

Comment: _I assumed that Me designated the object in the scoped With_ no, it does not.  In a comment to the Q you said _Code is in Trials under a Private Sub_ if this code is in the `Trials` module (listed under the "Microsoft Excel Objects" in the VBA editor) then `Me` refers to the `Trials` sheet.  The with block object is referenced with a leading `.` (as you have done with `.Rows` in `Me.Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row`)

Comment: Can I get you to clear up one last thing for me? I'm getting a type mismatch with the check = .Evaluate..... line and after testing, it centers on the namecheck.Value and vencheck.Value. I've used similar code elsewhere and it works, but not here for some reason. Tried rewriting it so that my code uses variants but that doesn't work. Here's the line that works already:
                                                                          
      rw = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Names and Vendors").Evaluate("MATCH(1,(B1:B" & lr & "=""" & arr(0) & """)*(C1:C" & lr & "=""" & arr(1) & """),0)")

Comment: What are the values of the variables at that point? Do they produce a valid formula string?

Answer (score -1):

The more correct answer to this question is that the With construct should be retricted to a simple sequence  of getters and setters of an object.

A good example of this is the Word Find object where the code below is common

```
With ActiveDocument.Content.Find
     .Text = "FindText"
     .Replacement.Text = "ReplaceText"
     .Forward = True
     .Wrap = wdFindStop
     Do While .Execute() = True
         .TypeParagraph
         .MoveLeft Unit:=wdWord, Count:=2, Extend:=wdExtend
         .Find.Replacement.Font.Italic = True
         .Font.Bold = True
         .Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd
     Loop
 End With
```

The more correct way to address the issue you raise is to use appropriate objects with local scope to provide the shortcuts you need  e.g

Rather than

```
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Program")

    'Do xyz

End With
```

Use

```
Dim mySourceWb  as excel.Worksheet
Set mySOurceWb = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Program")
Dim myDestWb as Excel.Worksheet
Set myDestWB = ADifferentWb.Sheets("YetAnotherSpreadsheet")

'Do xyz

set mySourceWb=nothing
set myDestWb=nothing
```